# How to say "What is the last price?" in German?

Tags: translation, definite-article, adjective-ending

In an antique shop in Germany, I wanted to ask what is the last price after discount (both the short form and the complete sentence).

By googling, I've found:

> was ist letzte preis ?

I wonder if it is the correct one to use, without using any definite articles like "der", and why "letzte"?

Comment: I am really not sure what you want to ask and I suspect that this is one more example where a cultural communication problem is wrongly reduced to a grammar question.

Comment: @Phira: Huh? you're not sure what I want to ask? Sorry but I've read your comment twice and didn't get what you mean really.

Comment: @Gigili: are you *inquiring* about the final price or are you trying to *reduce* the final price by asking a suggestive question?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Both, I wanted to know the price and realize if there is a price reduction possibility.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While bernd_k posted several alternatives for asking whether it's the last price, if you want to know what the last price is (and not *whether* it is one), try one of these:

- Was ist der endgültige Preis?
- Was kostet [das Objekt] am Ende / letztendlich / unterm Strich?
- Wie viel muss ich bezahlen?

There are, of course, a lot of alternatives if you're still negotiating. bernd_k's examples fall into this category. If you want to ask if the seller will go down, you can ask, for example:

- Kann man da noch [preislich] etwas machen?

In the example you found, the article is required, but I think you wouldn't actually say "Was ist der letzte Preis?" in German. At least I never heard that.

Comment: It should be "endgültige" or "endgültiger"?

Comment: @Gigili: It's "endgültiger Preis" or "der endgültige Preis", because it's "der Preis".

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not correct. Better forms are

> Ist das Ihr letzter Preis?
>
> Ist das Ihr endgültiger Preis?
>
> Ist das Ihr letztes Angebot?

Here the goods have no fixed prices. Prices will be negotiated.

Comment: Oder auch "Ist das der letzte Preis?"

Comment: You can replace 'Ihr' by 'der'. The usage depends whether you think that the other can decide to reduce the price himself or not.

Comment: ... meaning: if you use 'ihr', you assume, he is, but if you use 'the', you leave it open.